# UIWebView with dynamic height inside a UIScrollView in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I am trying to make a UIWebView with "dynamic screen height". This webview is inside a UIScrollView, below other components. See the layout (it uses autolayout):

[image]

My idea is to provide just one scroll (from UIScrollView - its working) and **make the WebView viewport grow depending the content size**. And its not working.

What I did to try to do this:

1. UIWebView property "scale page to fit " is on;
2. UIWebView is unpaginated;
3. UIWebView does not allow user interaction.

In my UIViewController:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSString *urlString = @"MY URL GOES HERE";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webViewDescription loadRequest:urlRequest];
    _webViewDescription.delegate = self;
    _webViewDescription.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _webViewDescription.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
```

My UIWebViewDelegate:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;

    webView.frame = frame;


    NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);

    _myScrollView.contentSize = webView.bounds.size;
}
```

When I run the code, it prints the correct UIScrollView size and UIWebView size. The UIScrollView height got bigger, but the UIWebView maintains the same height from the first loading.

I am testing in a real device.

Comment: Dynamic height I set.But I have not set it for layout constraint.I ask you.Does my code useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a height constraint to your webView and make a IBOutlet of that like

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *webViewHeightConstraint;
```

load your webview and in web view delegate

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

get webview content height and set `webViewHeightConstraint.constant`
like below:-

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

    NSString *str = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;"];
    CGFloat height = str.floatValue;
    webViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;

}
```

hope it may help you.

Comment: Simply you got it.

Comment: @user3182143 Happy Coding !Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `webView.frame = frame;` in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Answer (score 0):

You can get the content size of webview content using `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height`.

and than you can use this `webView.scrollView.contentSize.height` to set the `contentSize` of the scrollview inside `webViewDidFinishLoad` method.

Like this in `webViewDidFinishLoad` method

```
[objWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(objWebView.frame.origin.x, objWebView.frame.origin.y, objWebView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)];
if(objWebView.frame.origin.y+objWebView.frame.size.height > objScrollView.contentSize.height) {
    [objScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(objScrollView.frame.size.width, objWebView.frame.origin.y+objWebView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: it did not changed the uiwebview content height.

Answer (score 0):

For setting dynamic height for UIWebView, you need to set the height in webViewDidFinishLoadView method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  CGFloat height = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
   //For Width
 //CGFloat width = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
 CGRect frame = webview1.frame;
 frame.size.height = height;
 //frame.size.width = width; //Width
 webview.frame = frame;

 CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds ;
 CGFloat widthForIpad = CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds)  ;
 CGFloat heightForIpad = CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds) ;
 NSLog(@"The iPad width is - %fl",widthForIpad);
 NSLog(@"The iPad height is - %fl",heightForIpad);

 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
 {
   if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
     scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, height+370); //set your required height
   else
     scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, height+350); //set your required height
  }
  else
  {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024)  
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, height+370);  //For iPad
  }
}
```